# Is it possible to create a seperate Dispatcher for an individual Control in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I've got a control that has to do quite a bit of work on the UI thread. It causes lags in other parts of the UI. At this moment it is not easy to break it apart and put work on a worker thread as most of the operations happen on dependency properties and they don't like to go cross thread.

However I was wondering if it is possible to isolate the control to it's own thread with it's own dispatcher. I'm not hopeful but was wondering.

I've seen solutions for windows but not for individual controls.

Comment: Have a look at [Multithreaded UI: HostVisual](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dwayneneed/archive/2007/04/26/multithreaded-ui-hostvisual.aspx). This is not a separate Dispatcher, but it might steer you in the right direction...

Comment: A Control shouldn't have to that much work.

Comment: Why don't you get the Dispatcher for your control and run the code on it. https://github.com/quitrk/MiniDeskTube/blob/master/DeskTube/ViewModels/MainPageViewModel.cs line 1542

Comment: @PotecaruTudor Why would I want to do that?

Comment: I'm not saying to run all the code on the Dispatcher, but the parts that should update your UI. This should help preventing the lagging in other parts of the UI. This is of course what worked for me, I don't know how your project is structured.

Comment: All UI code runs on the dispatcher. The dispatcher is single threaded. If some UI code is too heavy then it slows down the dispatcher. One solution is to move stuff to a worker thread. However if you are manipulating WriteableBitmap objects with WriteableBitmapEX then there is no way to do this other than on the dispatcher which is a total PITA as it slows down other things.

Answer (score 1):

```
var controlThread = new Thread(() => 
{
    var window = new MyWindow();
    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
});

controlThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
controlThread.Start();
```

EDIT: Clemens is right, you obviously cannot simply add the control to a container of another thread. However, if such integration is not a hard requirement from an UI standpoint, you could make this work by making your control a Window.

Another approach would be to wrap a window with your control within another control. Then you could remove the window's borders and make position, size and visibility match.

Comment: This doesn't help much. You would have to add the control to some container control in the surrounding application, which would inevitably raise an InvalidOperationException saying "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it".